# Pandas DataReader: normalizing dates

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I use pandas data reader package to pull economic time series from website like fred, yahoo finance. I have pulled us recession (USREC) series from the 'fred' website and historical sp500 (^GSPC) from yahoo finance.

Historical US recession:

```
web.DataReader("USREC", "fred", start, end)
```

Output:

```
2017-08-01      0
2017-09-01      0
2017-10-01      0
2017-11-01      0
```

S&P500 returns

```
web.DataReader("^GSPC",'yahoo',start,end)['Close'].to_frame().resample('M').mean().round()
```

Output:

```
2017-08-31  2456.0
2017-09-30  2493.0
2017-10-31  2557.0
2017-11-30  2594.0
```

I want to merge the two data frames, but one has beginning date of the month and other has ending date of the month. How do I make a) the date column yyyy-mm b) either make the date column of both frames month beginning or month end?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MS` for resample by start of months:

```
web.DataReader("^GSPC",'yahoo',start,end)['Close'].to_frame().resample('MS').mean().round()
```

Or is possible use [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_period.html) for month `PeriodIndex`:

```
df1 = df1.to_period('M')
df2 = df2.to_period('M')
print (df1)
         Close
2017-08      0
2017-09      0
2017-10      0
2017-11      0

print (df2)
          Close
2017-08  2456.0
2017-09  2493.0
2017-10  2557.0
2017-11  2594.0

print (df1.index)
PeriodIndex(['2017-08', '2017-09', '2017-10', '2017-11'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M')

print (df2.index)
PeriodIndex(['2017-08', '2017-09', '2017-10', '2017-11'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```